# Valgrind says invalid write, but I'm just assigning to a string

Tags: c++, valgrind

I've been at this for half a day and can't figure out why Valgrind is unhappy.

Valgrind whines:

```
==25658== Invalid write of size 4
==25658==    at 0x40242F: MyObject::copy(MyObject const&) (MyObject.cpp:96)
==25658==    by 0x402264: MyObject::operator=(MyObject const&) (MyObject.cpp:40)
```

MyObject.cpp:96 is in my copy function

```
 94 void MyObject::copy(const MyObject & other)
 95 {
 96         myVariable = other.myVariable;
```

MyObject.cpp:40 is in the assignment operator

```
 36 MyObject & MyObject::operator=(const MyObject & other)
 37 {
 38         if (this != &other)
 39         {
 40                 copy(other);
 41         }
 42         return *this; 
 43 }
```

MyVariable is of type String

```
 17 class MyObject
 18 {
 19         public:
 20 
 21         /** My Variable */
 22         string myVariable;
```

I can't see any reason why Valgrind would find a problem with this code. What am I missing?

Comment: is the "other" object initialized ?

Comment: Could you construct a minimal but complete test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm working on Yochai's suggestion right now, he may be right. I may be relying on Valgrind too much -- time to break out the debug statements.

Comment: Yochai, you were right. I just had to put in some print statements to find out what was going wrong. If you answer the question I'll remove my answer and mark you as accepted. Thanks for helping me get to bed earlier!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be me writing out of the bounds of an Array.

Yochai, thank you for the comment. That was the problem. The object was never initialized because it was assigned to an invalid index of an array.